# how to write a nested xpath xpression based on other elements in the div?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, nested, fluentlenium

I need to find a button using xpath and want to try using a nested xpath xpression.

I've been using the expression

```
 @FindBy(xpath="//*/button[contains(text(),'FOO')]")
```

to find instances of other buttons elsewhere in the code and so far this works fine. however My code is dynamically creating multiple instances of an 'Add' button on the page and sometimes these add buttons are invisible

Is it possible to write an Xpath expression that can find a button with the text  'Add' that is inside a `div` that has a has a `h1` containing text 'panel visible'?

Here is a redacted version of the HTML as it currently exists

```
<div class="foo1">
<div class="foo2">
<div class="foo3">
<div class="foo4">
<div class="foo5">
<h1 >New Contact</h1>
</div>
<div >
<div >
<div >
<span >
<button >Add</button>
</span>
```

Comment: yep, this is entirely possible. You'll need to provide some html really to get further help though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//div/h1[contains(text(), 'panel visible')]/button[contains(text(), 'Add')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked, but is tightly coupled

```
@FindBy(xpath="//h1[contains(text(), 'Panel visible')]/../../..//button[contains(text(), 'Add')]")
```

This was a better answer and is more loosely coupled

```
(xpath="//*[contains(concat(' ', @foo, ' '), ' foo_container ')][descendant::h1[contains(text(), 'Panel visible')]]//button[contains(text(), 'Add')]")
```